# For prime $p$, show that $p\mid a^n\Rightarrow p\mid a$

Tags: divisibility

I already try to solve this with divisibility rule
$p = ka, a^n$  = $ka*ka$ as much as $n$ times
$a^n≡a (mod n)$, then $p^n=ka*ka$
therefore $p^n= a^n$ be $^n√p^n|^n√a^n$ which $p|a$
but im not sure how right am i or wrong

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you can use the fact that a prime $p$ divides $x y$ iff it divides either $x$ or $y$, (Euclid's lemma) this is just induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. You could use the contraposition for example. But I think the best way to understand the relation is the direct way.

Let $p$ be a prime with $p\mid a^n$ for some natural $a$ and $n$.
If $a = p$, we are done. Now look at the unique prime decomposition of a:
$$
a = p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_k
$$
where every $p_i$ is a prime number.
These do not have to be distinct.
Then
$$
a^n 
= (p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_k)^n
= p_1^n \cdot p_2^n \cdot \dots \cdot p_k^n.
$$
Since $p$ is a divisor of $a^n$, there is a prime number $p_i$ in this decomposition, such that
$$
p\mid p_i^n.
$$
But since $p$ and $p_i$ are prime, it follows that $p = p_i$ (because multiplying two numbers does not lead to new divisors).
So
$$
p\mid p_i\mid a 
\Rightarrow
p\mid a.
$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)